# Is it possible to use document.innerHTML to print out a .txt file?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use document.innerHTML to print out all the text from a .txt file? I'm trying to swap all the code in the c1 anchor from this

```
<div class="bigtext">
    <a id="c1"><img src="portraits/Random_0.jpg" width="60px" height="60px" alt=random></img>Random</a>
    </div>
```

to this

```
<div class="bigtext">
    <a id="c1"><img src="portraits/Otherthing_0.jpg" width="60px" height="60px" alt=random></img>Other Thing</a>
    </div>
```

I'm calling this Javascript function that gets triggered when pressing on a picture using onClick()

```
   function bubby() {
document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML=(text.txt);
}
```

But it's not working properly, it works when I do the innerHTML command in quotes but that only seems to work for small pieces of text, and I need to print out lines of code with quotes in them.

Comment: use innerText instead of innerHTML (for firefox use the W3C-compliant textContent property)

Comment: Look at using XML instead, it will allow you to display text with quotes that will not allow ' or " to effect the script executing your commands. Also, if you are using javascript to execute commands on the user's end, but your text file is on the server, how do you intend for the file to be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access file system. So, NO.

As workaround you can fetch a content of the file using XHR and append it to the `#c1` element.

Comment: Did I miss anything? It's not about loading a file from the local file system is it?